# Django logging not working in production

Tags: django, logging, python-2.7, production, archlinux

I am not able to get logging work in production (arch linux). On local machine it works fine. Here are the logging settings:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': 'LEVEL:%(levelname)s TIME:%(asctime)s MODULE:%(module)s LINE:%(lineno)d PROCESS:%(process)d THREAD:%(thread)d MESSAGE:%(message)s'
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'logfile': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename':  "logs/logfile314.txt",
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'myLog': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

}

When I deploy this to production I saw this error in apache log:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'logfile': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/http/logs/logfile314.txt'
```

So I went and fixed permissions on `/srv/http/logs` to :

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4.0K Aug 21 16:05 logs
```

Now the application doesn't even start and after 2-3 minutes front page loading breaks and in apache log there is this error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Aug 21 16:05:58 2013] [notice] child pid 32559 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Aug 21 16:11:03 2013] [error] [client 89.142.110.111] Premature end of script headers: wsgi.py
```

But I haven' changed wsgi.py in a long time. Everything works ok, if I remove my setting for logging or if I gave path to which http user does not have permissions. I tried putting the absolute path to log file, since `/srv/http/logs` probaly isn't the right place to put log files, but even this doesn't work.

Any ideas or suggestions how to get logging to work on production also?

Comment: Is Apache running as root?

Comment: It's running as http.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by putting this line of code to apache configuration file:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Explanation could be found here: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error. I found that if I created a new folder and file, the user-name and group-name are both Apache. The error will be missed.